# Jasmine what tests to write for a filter form

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, jasmine

I am new to unit testing... I am trying to figure out what tests to write for a filter form.

example:

```
<form action="" id="filters">
    <p><label for="">Speed</label>
       <select name="speed" id="speed">
    <option value="ALL">All</option>
    <option value="SLOW">Slow</option>
    <option value="NORMAL">Normal</option>
    <option value="FAST">Fast</option>
    <option value="TURBO">Turbo</option>
    </select>
```

On change I have to send a request to server and populate a table with the new results.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mildly subjective question, but what I would do in your case is test to make sure:

- All the various queries are able to made correctly (you can do this by using jQuery to manipulate the widget to test the `change` event handler for the widget)
- All the responses from the queries are parseable
- That a malformed request is caught and handled appropriately
- That a malformed response is caught and dealt with
- That the widget renders (calling `.render()` and then checking to make sure the items inserted into the DOM are present in the page DOM)
- That all the various options are present

etc...